# Run Google Apps Script on Google-Spreadsheet event?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers

If I create a Google apps script, can I hook it up to Google spreadsheet to run based on an event, or must I manually invoke it?

I don't know if Google Sheets supports any events.

For example: a Google app script that strikes out rows in the spreadsheet that have been marked completed by way of a column having the digit 1 beside completed rows. I would like this to run whenever a row is modified, or even when the spreadsheet is first loaded.

Comment: Removed google-app-engine tag, as this question is not actually related to AppEngine in any way.

Comment: @Adam C: Thanks, I was unsure when I posted that tag - figured somebody else would know the diff and correct it if need be.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function `onOpen()` is automatically executed every time a Spreadsheet is loaded. In the future, we will expose a general event API, but until then you can simply define your own function as long as it is called `onOpen()`.

From the Section 2 of the [Tutorial](http://www.google.com/google-d-s/scripts/defining_menus.html)

There is also function `onEdit()` as can be viewed in at:

http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/apps-script/thread?tid=584a17c79e4c04d5&hl=en

It seems that event handling is in flux and dependent on security issues being worked out.

Comment: Out of curiosity would you per chance be a Google employee on the Docs team? ref: "we"

Comment: @jdk I am not a Google employee. The 'we' was part of the tutorial I copied and pasted. Should have been more specific about attribute-From the Section 2 of the Tutorial.